# What is this purple flower called?

Tags: identification, flowers

I have started a new embroidery project and have been looking for real-life flowers which match the one in my project.

I found one like this, which seems to sort of match and which I really like the coloring of, but I don't know the name of it. What's this purple flower called?

[image: found picture]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flower pictured is one of the cranesbill Geraniums (not to be confused with the general term geranium often used for Pelargoniums). There are hundreds of varieties and definite ID is a little easier if the foliage is visible, but I have found one called Geranium 'Alan Mayes' which closely resembles your image, see here http://www.plantpref.co.uk/all-other-geraniums.html. It might not be that one, as already said, there are literally hundreds of them, but you might decide its close enough!